# javafx binding from list property to arbitrary object property

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to get a class to have a property bound to another class's list property, where the 1st property is derived from a summarizing calculation over the objects in the list. The code below is a simplified version of my production code. (The production code is doing a summary over DateTime objects -- the essential part of the code below is the binding between a list and an object property (here, it is a String for simplicity).)

I have tried various things. One approach was using `addListener` on the list in the Summary class below but I was running into weird bugs with the listener callback making updates on the Summary object. After doing a bunch of reading I think that a binding between the summary string and the list is more appropriate but I don't know exactly how to hook up the binding to the property?

```
package com.example.demo.view

import javafx.beans.Observable
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import tornadofx.View
import tornadofx.button
import tornadofx.label
import tornadofx.vbox

class Thing(x: Int) {
    val xProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(x)
    val yProperty = SimpleStringProperty("xyz")
}

class Collection {
    private var things = FXCollections.observableList(mutableListOf<Thing>()) {
        arrayOf<Observable>(it.xProperty)
    }

    val thingsProperty = SimpleListProperty<Thing>(things)

    fun addThing(thing: Thing) {
        things.add(thing)
    }
}

class Summary(var collection: Collection) {
    val summaryBinding = object : StringBinding() {
        // The real code is more practical but
        // this is just a minimal example.
        override fun computeValue(): String {
            val sum = collection.thingsProperty.value
                .map { it.xProperty.value }
                .fold(0, { total, next -> total + next })
            return "There are $sum things."
        }
    }

    // How to make this property update when collection changes?
    val summaryProperty = SimpleStringProperty("There are ? things.")
}

class MainView : View() {
    val summary = Summary(Collection())

    override val root = vbox {
        label(summary.summaryProperty)
        button("Add Thing") {
            summary.collection.addThing(Thing(5))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that I made this answer based on your minimal example:

```
class Thing(x: Int) {
    val xProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(x)
    var x by xProperty

    val yProperty = SimpleStringProperty("xyz")
    var y by yProperty
}


class MainView : View() {
    val things = FXCollections.observableList(mutableListOf<Thing>()) {
        arrayOf<Observable>(it.xProperty)
    }

    val thingsProperty = SimpleListProperty<Thing>(things)

    val totalBinding = integerBinding(listProperty) {
        value.map { it.x }.fold(0, { total, next -> total + next })
    }

    val phraseBinding = stringBinding(totalBinding) { "There are $value things." }

    override val root = vbox {
        label(phraseBinding)
        button("Add Thing") {
            action {
                list.add(Thing(5))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I removed your other classes because I didn't see a reason for them based on the example. If the collection class has more functionality than holding a list property in your real project, then add just add it back in. If not, then there's no reason to give a list its own class. The summary class is really just two bindings (or one if you have no need to separate the total from the phrase). I don't see the need to give them their own class either unless you plan on using them in multiple views.

I think your biggest problem is that you didn't wrap your button's action in `action {}`. So your code just added a `Thing(5)` on init and had no action set.

P.S. The `var x by xProperty` stuff will only work if you `import tornadofx.*` for that file.

Comment: I think the biggest insight for me here is that tornadofx provides `stringBinding` and `integerBinding` which somewhat simplifies things. Can I use the resulting binding objects as if they were properties in most places?

Comment: Also you said "Lastly, the list bindings only react to the list changing (adding/removing items). It does not listen for item properties to change." -- this isn't true, that's what the `arrayOf<Observable>(it.xProperty)` syntax in my code does. (I verified this by adding another button to my example that changes xProperty.value on the first element in the list, and I can see the total change.)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that! I tested it out and you're right. I've adjusted my answer accordingly. And, yes, bindings have much of the functionality as read-only properties. I often use them for labels and binding things like a component's disabled property. I would also like to mention that in a real project, the list and list property should probably be put in something like a  Controller or Presenter class.